# Flutter TextFormField cursor is focused but not accepted input text

Tags: flutter, dart

After clear text in TextFormField below code:

```
Widget _textInputNumber({controller, name, enable, autofocus, required}) {
    return TextFormField(
      autofocus: autofocus,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
      enabled: enable,
      controller: controller,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        filled: true,
        fillColor: Colors.white,
        suffix: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            controller.text = '';
            setState(() {});
          },
          child: const Icon(
            Icons.clear,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      validator: required
          ? (value) => value!.isEmpty ? 'Required!' : null
          : null,
      onSaved: (value) => name = value,
    );
  }
```

Cursor is focused but not accepted input text I need again click on focused input to enter new text.

Any solution?

Comment: ok, & what do you want, can you include full TextField on sample widget

Comment: @YeasinSheikh  What to do so that I don't have to click twice! Already immediately after the text is cleared, I can enter a new value!

Comment: please provide your full sample widget TextFormField

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I'm add my source code and update question!

Comment: It is working for me, can you include from scaffold

Answer (score 1):

you can solve issue by calling this code `FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode())`

Here's the full code:

```
Widget _textInputNumber({controller, name, enable, autofocus, required}) {
    return TextFormField(
      autofocus: autofocus,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
      enabled: enable,
      controller: controller,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        filled: true,
        fillColor: Colors.white,
        suffix: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            controller.text = '';
            setState(() {});
            FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
          },
          child: const Icon(
            Icons.clear,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      validator: required
          ? (value) => value!.isEmpty ? 'Required!' : null
          : null,
      onSaved: (value) => name = value,
    );
  }
```

Comment: interestingly, when I click on clear the keyboard hides and loses focus.

Comment: Try to wrap GestureDetector: GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    controller.text = '';
    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
  },
  child: TextFormField(
    ...
  ),
)

Comment: don't see differences after use GestureDetector!

Comment: in TextformField add : enabled: true and autofucos: false

Comment: and btw. dont forget to add controller in TextFormField